# Disallow folder browsing but allow file requests (Apache)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, file, security, directory

Is it possible to configure Apache to disallow websurfers to access particular folders and seeing a directory listing but allow browsers to retrieve files from those folders. Let's say you have some images in a folder, you might want to allow users to see specific ones but not to view the contents of the entire folder. The user can only see the ones known to exist on the server in a particular folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is indeed possible using any of these directives:

```
Options -Indexes
```

OR

```
IndexIgnore *
```

Comment: But files can still be retrived from the directory by the browser, right?

Comment: Yes that is right, files can be retrieved in browsers.